# How to use string resource in a Java class in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, resources, android-resources

In my Java class I want to use a string resource from strings.xml.

For that I want to use something like this:

```
getString(R.string.address)
```

If my class is an activity then it's working.
But how can I use it if my class is a simple Java class?

Comment: If your project is a Android project.definitely you can use it.Have you tried it? try to use it then tell us.

Comment: I'm curious what your logic was when you accepted the answer you did.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A class does not have a context and to use a string resource a context is needed. So just call the class from an activity and give a parameter `context` and within your class constructor just use that context to get the string resource.

In your custom class you need to import the R namespace for the project to get the resource Id.

```
import com.myrandomapp.R;
```

Then to get the actual string

```
context.getString(R.string.COOL_STRING)
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete - To complete for those who still have questions, you need to import the R namespace for the project to get the resource Id.  example) import com.myappdomain.R (USE YOUR NAMESPACE HERE)

Then to get the actual string 
context.getString(R.string.SOME_STRING)

Comment: @AndroidAddict +1 for you, you save me a headache!

Answer (score 17):

You can pass the context of the Activity class to the java class and access the resources.

From your Activity Class

```
 Helper helper = new Helper(this);
```

Your Java class

```
public class Helper {

    Helper(Context c){
        c.getString(R.string.address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can create a static `Application Context` in your custom `Application` class

```
public class App extends Application{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to call `App.getContext().getResources()` to get any resource values.

Just remember that this `Context` is `Application` type, so there are things that this `Context` is not good to use. Read [this](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) for further info.

Comment: Android Studio complains about memory leaks for Context objects in static fields - would you do this differently now?

Answer (score -1):

You could done if you add this line:

```
// this is the object itself, and idString is the ID String bound to the literal.
this.getString(R.string.idString)
```

I hope this comment helps you!

Brs.