# Android: Getting string from strings.xml in Java code

Tags: java, android, xml

First of all, please note I´ve been trying to search and existing answer to this question. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102741/android-how-to-use-string-resource-in-a-java-class), but is not helping.

I am simply trying to get strings from regular Java (domain) classes within an Android app, but I am not able to get them by using `getResources()`.

Is this possible? (I´d like to avoid creating a new `strings.xml` alike file in order to centralize all the strings within the app)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Am I forced to pass Context to every single Java class? Is there any way to avoiding it?

Comment: Make a class and define static/non static  String values to access them.

Comment: pass context to the Java classes in their constructors. Assign this context to class variable. Then you can do mContext.getResources().getString(---)

You will have to also import the R.java in this class

Comment: @ArjunGurung is there any other way?

Comment: @stackman if you dont want to pass context and use getResources which is best method to use, making a class is only method i know..

Comment: @ArjunGurung thanks man

Answer (score 5):

Pass context to the Java classes in their constructors. Assign this context to class variable. 
Then you can do mContext.getResources().getString(---)

You will have to also import the R.java in this class

Comment: please see my Edit

Answer (score 3):

You need to have access to a Context object (passing it so a non android class e.g.).

Using this Context you can call `context.getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);`

Comment: please see my Edit